# SWIFT PDFKIT Hyphenation not working on a justified text

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, pdfkit

Hyphenation on a justified text works in an UITextView but doesn't seem to work in a text drawn on a PDF (PDFView) using PDFKit.

[image: PDFView on the left, UITextView on the right]

The same attributed string drawn on the PDFView was assigned to the UITextView attributed string value. Any suggestions?

This occurs only when the text is justified. Using a different text alignment shows hyphenation correctly also on the PDFView.

Here's the code for drawing on the PDFView in the `pdfData` method of a `UIGraphicsPDFRenderer`:

```swift
let paragraphStyleArticle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyleArticle.hyphenationFactor = 1.0
            paragraphStyleArticle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
            paragraphStyleArticle.alignment = .justified

            let attributesArticle = [
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13),
                NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyleArticle
            ]
            let article = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean id nulla in nisl egestas blandit vitae viverra velit. Vestibulum est diam, vestibulum vel tristique interdum, consequat vitae ex. Morbi cursus nulla ut dignissim vestibulum. Sed placerat eget mauris quis interdum. Fusce consequat orci a hendrerit auctor. Etiam vulputate tincidunt magna vel pellentesque. Donec sit amet lacinia est, vel sodales velit. Phasellus pharetra dolor nec blandit venenatis. Donec vel commodo odio. Integer iaculis lectus sit amet ex ultrices cursus. Pellentesque quis orci vel purus porttitor pretium sit amet vitae urna. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.\n\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean id nulla in nisl egestas blandit vitae viverra velit. Vestibulum est diam, vestibulum vel tristique interdum, consequat vitae ex. Morbi cursus nulla ut dignissim vestibulum. Sed placerat eget mauris quis interdum. Fusce consequat orci a hendrerit auctor. Etiam vulputate tincidunt magna vel pellentesque. Donec sit amet lacinia est, vel sodales velit. Phasellus pharetra dolor nec blandit venenatis. Donec vel commodo odio. Integer iaculis lectus sit amet ex ultrices cursus. Pellentesque quis orci vel purus porttitor pretium sit amet vitae urna. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.\n\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean id nulla in nisl egestas blandit vitae viverra velit. Vestibulum est diam, vestibulum vel tristique interdum, consequat vitae ex. Morbi cursus nulla ut dignissim vestibulum. Sed placerat eget mauris quis interdum. Fusce consequat orci a hendrerit auctor. Etiam vulputate tincidunt magna vel pellentesque. Donec sit amet lacinia est, vel sodales velit. Phasellus pharetra dolor nec blandit venenatis. Donec vel commodo odio. Integer iaculis lectus sit amet ex ultrices cursus. Pellentesque quis orci vel purus porttitor pretium sit amet vitae urna. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus."
            let attributedPDFArticle = NSAttributedString(string: article, attributes: attributesArticle)
            let textSizeArticle = attributedPDFArticle.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: pdfView.bounds.width - 10, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
            let textRectArticle = CGRect(x: pdfView.bounds.width / 2 - textSizeArticle.width / 2, y: 40, width: textSizeArticle.width, height: textSizeArticle.height)
            
            article.draw(in: textRectArticle, withAttributes: attributesArticle)
```

And I simply assign the same attributed string to the text view:

```swift
textView.attributedText = attributedPDFArticle
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like .**justified** and **hyphenationFactor** do not work. As your purpose is to keep the text alignment justified with hyphenationFactor and it is working for UITextView. An alternate solution is to use the UITextView and convert it to PDFData.  You don't need the **article.draw**. Here is the sample:

```
let textView = UITextView(frame: textRectArticle)
textView.attributedText = attributedPDFArticle
textView.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
// Remove this code
// article.draw(in: textRectArticle, withAttributes: attributesArticle)
```

Here is the output.

[image]

Comment: Interesting workaround but sadly rendering the layer like that makes the rendered text in the PDFDocument to work like an image rather than a text, so it's not the result I'm looking for.